# Deleting a message if it contains a specific word

Tags: discord, discord.js, bots

So im making a discord bot, i made a system so if the bot joins a server it sends a message with the server name in the developer server. but i want it to delete the message when it leaves the server. idk how to do that.

Comment: You need to save bot message ID somewhere, better in database, and when your bot leaves the server - you search for this message by ID and delete it

Comment: Can you show the code so far, what are you stuck on?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a listener that is triggered whenever a user sends a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message). In that listener you would check the [`message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) against your prohibited word(s) and delete it. You can do that like so:

```js
client.on('messageCreate', () => {
    if(message.content.includes("Your prohibited word(s)") {
        message.delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: yea but its in the guildDelete event. so `messageCreate` and `message` doesn't work

Comment: @Kaytitulaer2008 For older messages it is impossible. You would have to loop over every single message sent in a guild which is so much work that it's API abuse.